# eBay API PHP & XML parse error when item's name contains ampersand

Tags: php, xml, parsing, ebay-api, ampersand

I have been testing my PHP app to list items on eBay using their Trading API. I have been having success in my testing but I just came accross some items with ampersand in the title.

This error keeps getting returned.

```
XML Error Text: "; nested exception is: 
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference
```

What its telling me is that I cant simply pass the ampersand symbol.

To remedy the problem I have tried several things:

```
$string = 'LEUPOLD 66325 4.5-14x50 VX-3 RIFLE SCOPE - SILVER, B&C BOONE & CROCKETT RETICLE';
echo str_replace("&","&amp;",$string);
echo str_replace("&","&amp;amp;",$string);
echo htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_NOQUOTES);
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
```

also tried it like this

```
<![CDATA['.$string.']]>
```

No matter what I do, it does not succeed when I pass it through.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Is the data you're submitting in UTF8? That could be your problem if it's not. http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/return-management/Concepts/MakingACall.html#utf8encoding

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was the problem. You should present your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the data you're submitting in UTF8? That could be your problem if it's not.

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/return-management/Concepts/MakingACall.html#utf8encoding

> All parameter values should be encoded in UTF-8 format. UTF-8 is the default encoding for API requests.